# "Illegal address in String" email template in CQ5 javax.mail

Tags: aem, jcr, jakarta-mail, crx

Working on a customised email template in CQ5, I have created in following text file under etc/notification. The workflow is triggered when a form is filled in by the user.

```
From: Order Brochure <order.brochures@gmail.com>
To: ${payload.email}
CC:
Subject: Order Brochures Confirmation ${payload.BrochureID}

Dear ${payload.Name},

Thank you for your Brochure Order, your reference is ${payload.orderBrochureID}.
Your email address is {$payload.email}.
```

Everything in this template works fine, except for the "To: ${payload.email}". Even the "Your email address is {$payload.email}" part displays the user inputted email fine. It also works if I input a static email address in "To:".

What am I doing wrong here? Below is the error in logs

```
Process execution resulted in an error:
javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal address in string ``''
com.day.cq.workflow.WorkflowException: javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal 
address in string ``''
```

Comment: Is this a custom workflow step or is it the com.day.cq.collab.commons.SendEmailProcess step?

Comment: This is a custom workflow step

Comment: if this is a custom workflow step could you provide the code that is parsing the internet addresses? The error message that you are receiving is a null error. Which would seem to indicate that you are attempting to extract the "to" address before applying the map for the string replacement utility.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. Apologies I misunderstood your question, it is infact com.day.cq.collab.commons.SendEmailProcess with

    HANDLER ADVANCE: ticked
    EMAIL TEMPLATE PATH: /etc/notification/emailConfirm.txt 
    EMAIL TEMPLATE: Empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "CC:" it's attempting to parse the email address for this header and it's a null.

When you're dealing with these types of problems when the error is occurring within a CQ library. I recommend using a custom logger to assist with the troubleshooting.

Details of logging can be found at [Logging - docs.day.com](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/deploying/configure_logging.html)

Here's an example OSGi log configuration for your issue.

[image: Logging Example]

Comment: Removing CC worked.

Will try out the loggin method you suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This error might be cumming because you are using a string as an Internet Address.
you need to typecast ${payload.email} to Internet Address.

Comment: I was suggesting that for a JSP not for a .txt format? Please elaborate your question?